# C# PSObject Members.Value

Tags: c#, psobject

I am trying to get on a PSObject "undervalue" in my GUI, but I don't have a clue how to get this into a variable.

The code looks like this:

```
foreach (PSObject outputItem in JobSession)
{
   if (outputItem != null)
   {
      dataGridView2.Rows.Add(outputItem.Members["JobName"].Value, outputItem.Members["CreationTime"].Value, outputItem.Members["Progress"].Value);
   }
}
```

The `outputItem.Members["Progress"].Value` one should give me a number that is under Value.

Picture:

[image]